# Are there direct flights from Santiago, Chile to Quito, Ecuador?

Tags: air-travel, santiago-de-chile, scl, quito

A colleague is trying to find this, and we're struggling, seeing only connecting flights via Lima or Panama.  Are we missing something? It seems odd that two South American capitals aren't directly connected...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.

You can actually easily check where you can fly from Quito via the [Airport's Website](http://www.quitoairport.aero/en/flights-and-airlines/flight-information/arrivals.html) looks like you are able to fly to Guayaquil

Comment: Had to find the international flights section, and there it does indicate a flight LA1446 from Santiago, but sadly it's 1-stop. Thanks!

Comment: An one stop flight from Santiago in Chili to Quito in Ecuador? Are you kidding? A short distance and not a direct flight?

Comment: @MarkMayo I can't find that flight currently in either departures or arrivals.  So it may be the issue of the date as it may not be a daily flight.

Comment: Yeah you go to the weekly schedule, and it shows as being on Fridays (and Tuesdays, I think).

Comment: @PersianCat it looks that way.  If you can prove his answer wrong, we'd be very keen to know.

Comment: The distances in South America are long, and there is not that much air traffic at all. It's almost 4000 km from Santiago to Quito - similar to the distance between NYC and LA. The LA1446/1447 pair is the closest thing to a direct flight between the cities, but their actual route is a big mess: http://info.flightmapper.net/flight/LAN_Airlines_LA_1446

Comment: @JouniSirén Based on this flight information it's a Santiago to Guayaquil to Quito.  May be the same plane but still makes a stop.

Comment: In Asia it is not a big distance for a flight!.. ;) ..

Answer (score 3):

It's been more than one year since the original question, so I guess these flights were not available back then, but now LAN Chile offers direct flights from Santiago to Quito, but not the other way around. I checked the schedule on momondo for a few days in March 2015, [here is an example](http://www.momondo.com/flightsearch/?Search=true&TripType=1&SegNo=1&SO0=SCL&SD0=UIO&SDP0=15-03-2015&AD=1&TK=ECO&DO=false&NA=false).

One-way flights for those days cost around 647 euro, but it reduces to around 500 euro if you book a return flight, so even if you're not planning to take the flight back to Chile, it might make sense to book it that way. I haven't checked it separately, but sometimes you get a better deal if you book open-jaw tickets rather than buying a one-way ticket, e.g. Santiago-Quito-Lima may be cheaper than Santiago-Quito for certain dates.